# "Boosting" with reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, votes

I noticed earlier that after you post a question, the up/down vote button is still there. Can you "boost" or give yourself reputation because this button is still here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try it. It will give you a message saying you can't vote for your own post:

[image]

Comment: Weird, I can upvote myself many times over. Of course I have to download the whole site, modify the code and open it in localhost for it to work ^^.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado how u downloded the site ??? infact i wnat to have one for myself !

Comment: Askubuntu is not opensource, so you can't download this website

Comment: shan't and can't are different things @Tachyons, In Firefox - File > Save Page As..